# Send To functionality does not work in document library

Tags: 2010, document-library, send-to-destination

I have a document library in which I have set the "Custom Send To Destination" in "Library settings > Advanced settings" to another document library in same site. The URL of destination document library is specified as `http://servername/sitename/libraryname`.

But when I try to use the "Send To" option it throws error "Copying to the destination did not complete successfully." This error appears on IE.

[image]

On Google Chrome it throws error but this time the message is "Value does not fall within the expected range."

I have access to both document libraries. I even tried to check out the document before using Send To option but it did not work.

What could be the cause here?